# What propriatory graphics driver do I need to install?

Tags: drivers, 15.10, ubuntu-gnome, additional-drivers

Here are the available ones:

[image: screenshot]

I have no idea which one I need. Is the one with highest number better? or the one that is tested?

Comment: The first one, nvidia-352.

Comment: I would recommend to chose the first option in both categories (`NVIDIA Binary driver - version 352.63 [...] (Proprietär, getestet)` and `Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs [...]`).

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to type in [Google](https://google.com/) phrase consisting of the following:

- Your graphics card model manufacturer and number
- Your Ubuntu version
- And driver version to check, like 352

If you are not seeing some reports in first results like "it is not working", the you should install **newest** (largest number) **tested** driver. Select those with **-updates** suffix.

If you get your PC/graphics processor more than 4 months ago, latest drivers are not about your card most definitely, they will not change much.